# Connect a frontend application with a Substrate blockchain as a backend without using an RPC endpoint

Tags: substrate-node, rpc, networking, libp2p, frontend

I'd like to connect my frontend application (built on Rust) to be able to connect to my network without using any hardcoded endpoints to create a bottleneck for DDoS attacks. One possibility for this could be to implement [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/client/network/src/service.rs#L601-L706) `sc-network` method for a library and use that library in my frontend app. But I'm still exploring any possibilities of this function to be constructed in a library. And I would also like to know whether it would be possible to implement [`NetworkBehaviour`](https://docs.rs/libp2p/latest/libp2p/swarm/index.html#network-behaviour) trait for my frontend so that it could be able to communicate with the rest of the [`Swarm`](https://docs.rs/libp2p/latest/libp2p/swarm/index.html#initializing-a-swarm), i.e my Substrate nodes without requiring any reference to an endpoint?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: So you want to connect from your frontend application to a Substrate node over P2P? What do you want to do with that P2P connection? Receive block announcements, request blocks, send transactions, identify the Substrate node?

Comment: Yes, receiving block announcements isn't important. I just want my frontend to identify my Substrate network and send transactions without using any hardcoded RPC endpoints.

Comment: https://github.com/lexnv/subp2p-explorer might be helpful. Sounds a lot like what you want to achieve

Comment: is providing boot nodes necessary? or is there any other way too e.g. using Kademlia random walk like [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/e5b2adac7ad5c44f0231af808e18258f4599c882/substrate/client/network/src/discovery.rs#L173)

Comment: I haven't tried to the tool myself but is it not possible to use your Substrate node as a bootnode?

Comment: yes, it is. I was just wondering about another possibility for the network discovery.

Comment: However, thank you for sharing this, I believe I can utilize it for my network.

Comment: @AaroAltonen I just needed one more confirmation, please. Does this libp2p crawler get only one node if more than one node is running on the same IP?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting a node"? I'm not author of the tool nor familiar with it so it maybe a good idea to open issue in the repository,